# Convert EF core query in raw SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, ef-core-3.1

Due to EF Core 3.x limitations, I need to convert a LINQ query in raw SQL.

The table looks like :

```
Id    Name      TagList
----------------------------
1    Line1      1;5;8
2    Line2      1;4
3    Line3      5
4    Line4      3;2;8
5    Line5
6    Line6      4
```

I need to get lines that matches a tag list provided has a parameter : let's call it tagSearch.
The EF query I've used with EF Core 2.x has Any() and Contains() method :

`var result= _myRepository.Where(a => a.TagList.Any(t => tagSearch.Contains(t)))`

if tagSearch is a `List<string>` that contains following items : 1 | 2

The result is :

```
Id    Name      TagList
----------------------------
1    Line1      1;5;8
2    Line2      1;4
4    Line4      3;2;8
```

I've tried several SQL queries with STRING_SPLIT and the closest is :

```
DECLARE @tagSearch NVARCHAR(400) = '1;2'  
SELECT *  
FROM MyTable
WHERE ( @tagSearch = SOME (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(TagList, ';')) 
        or TagList = SOME (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tagSearch, ';'))
)
```

But the result is not the one expected.

Comment: Better still (and IMO mandatory): normalize the database. Don't store CSVs. Turn it into a normal many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Your EF Core 2.x code shows `TagList` is a collection, but your example table does not show that - what is the type of `TagList`? You can convert your query to EF Core 3.x, if we knew what it was.

Comment: TagList is a string in the database and an IEnumerable in EF. I use a ValueConverter to convert string to enumerable and enumerable to string. I choose this design to avoid many-to-many tables for simple cases like tag management.